# Calculus 2 - $\ln (1+x)$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to proof that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(1/2)^n}{n}$ converges to $\ln(1+\frac{1}{2})$. But I am having difficulties showing that $r_n \rightarrow 0$. I get that $r_n=|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1}|$. By calculating the first few derivatives I got: $(\ln(1+x))'=\frac{1}{1+x},(\ln(1+x))''=-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2},(\ln(1+x))'''=\frac{2}{(1+x)^3},(\ln(1+x))^{(4)}=\frac{3!}{(1+x)^4},...,(\ln(1+x))^{(n)}=(-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$. If I try to take a point $0<c<\frac{1}{2}$ which will give an upper bound for $r_n$, I get $c=0$. But then I get $r_n=|\frac{(n-1)!(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1}|$ which does not converges to zero.
I am sure I am doing something wrong, for some reason, can't find it. What do you think??
Thank you!
Shir

Comment: What's lan? Do you mean $\ln$?

Comment: yes.. I'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

Your error formula for Taylor's Theorem should have $(n+1)!$ in the denominator.

However, an easier way to get this estimate is to start with the geometric series itself:
$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n+\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\,, \quad {x\ne 1}.$$
We then can get the error term for $\log$ by integrating and estimating:
$$-\log(1-x) = x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\dots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + \int_0^x \frac{t^{n+1}}{1-t}\,dt\,,\quad |x|<1\,.$$
As you point out, we want this for $x=-1/2$, so we need an upper bound on the integral:
$$\left|\int_0^{-1/2} \frac{t^{n+1}}{1-t}\,dt\right| \le \int_0^{1/2} \frac{t^{n+1}}{1+t}\,dt\,.$$
I leave it to you to show that you can obtain $\dfrac1{n+2}\left(\dfrac12\right)^{n+2}$ as an upper bound.

Comment: I don't think I got youre first note.. here for example the denominator is not (n+1)! http://www.math.sc.edu/~girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Comment: Look at formula (5) or (6) on the last page.

Comment: Got it now.. Thank you!

Comment: @Shir: You're welcome. If you're satisfied, you should accept the answer so that the question goes off the "needs an answer" list :)

Comment: I see.. OK I will try to find out how to do that. Thanks!